# How do I retrieve and display selected values from chained select boxes without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two chained select boxes where the second drop down populates based on the value of the first drop down and that works well. I currently have a php function that retrieves and displays the values of the selectboxes when users click on a button. Now the challenge I have is because they have to click the button to display the options they selected, the page is refreshed but I want a way where the options selected can be retrieved and displayed so the users can see what they choose without the page refreshing. I know this can be achieved using ajax but I am new to ajax and I have checked so many similar problems online but I do not quite understand how to make this work. Any advise on this will be very much appreciated. Please see below my php function that performs the retrieve and display of the selected values

```
function OutputCategory() {
    if (isset($_POST['drop_2']) && ($_POST['btn_confirm']) && ($_POST['drop_1'])) {
        $drop2 = $_POST['drop_2'];
        $drop1 = $_POST['drop_1'];

        $cat_name = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT subcategory_name FROM subcategory WHERE subcategory_id = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($drop2)));
        while ($cat_name1 = mysql_fetch_array($cat_name)) {
            $cat_name2 = $cat_name1['subcategory_name'];
        }

        $cat = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE category_id = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($drop1)));
        while ($cat1 = mysql_fetch_array($cat)) {
            $cat_2 = $cat1['category_name'];
        }
        echo "You selected Category:";
        echo $cat_2." >> ".$cat_name2;
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['drop_1']) && ($_POST['btn_confirm'])) {
        $drop1 = $_POST['drop_1'];
        $cat = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE category_id = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($drop1)));
        while ($cat1 = mysql_fetch_array($cat)) {
            $cat_2 = $cat1['category_name'];

            echo "You selected Category:";
            echo $cat_2;
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: many example for dependent selects ... no answer is able to save the efforts ... it is good to search the net first ... you will find a lot of examples ... generally AJAX which adds new select options when first on the other select onchange event ... please search this site too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to bind an ajax call to the select, something like this:

```
$('#select1_id').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      'select1_val': $(this).val()
    },
    url: 'some_page.php',
    success: function( data ) {
      $select2 = $('#select2_id');
      $select2.empty();      

      $(data.options).each(function(i,option){
        // append option to $select2
      });
    } 

  });
});
```

Then, on "some_page.php", hae something like this:

```
if( $_GET['select1_val'] ) {

  // get the select 2 vals, put them into an $array
  json_encode(array('options' => $array )); exit;

}
```

... although this is of course a very simple example, I'm sure you get the idea

Cheers,

Comment: `.onchange` will be better ... and if there is some other then english encoding should set it first ... but generally ...that's the way

Comment: oops - yeah - you're right about 'change' instead of 'click' for sure

Comment: also  the php part was just for demo purposes, if I were doing this I'd be using a REST api or such

Comment: yes i see :) the guy should make some efforts by him self ... it is a very common issue and he can find tones of solutions in google

Comment: I dunno, it took me forever to figure out how to work with jquery / ajax properly, so I figured I'd put an answer out

Comment: The main idea of this site is to help people which are started something but have a partucular problem ...so other people can help ... but the site is not made to do the job instead of the developer :) That's why I do not tolerate so called 'lazy' developers :) That's my believe. I never asked a solution here (just a principal question), because most of the things I can manage by myself. Just I bit more efforts. But i'm glad to help every person which is stuck in the middle :) I don't blame the guy ... he is novice here ... just reminding him to search before ask